# How to make the image move forward properly when rotated in my HTML5 game?

Tags: game-mechanics, html5, html-canvas

I am just trying to make a simple 2D racing game using canvas. It uses the <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> keys to move the car.  The <kbd>W</kbd> key should take me forward and the <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> keys will turn each way. I want the car to continue heading forward after being turned.  I am currently just multiplying the distance to move by the sin or cosine of the angle in order to find the x and y positions, but it is not reacting how I would expect. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas_layer_01" width="3072" height="2048" style="border:1px solid #000000;">></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_layer_01");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  car_image = new Image();
  car_image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/Bl2p5KI.png';

  var key_pressed_a = false,
    key_pressed_d = false,
    key_pressed_w = false,
    key_pressed_s = false;

  var player_x = 50,
    player_y = 50,
    player_speed = 10,
    player_angle = 0,
    max_turn_angle = 10; // probably needs to change based on speed

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
      case 87:
        key_pressed_w = true;
        break;

      case 83:
        key_pressed_s = true;
        break;

      case 65:
        key_pressed_a = true;
        break;

      case 68:
        key_pressed_d = true;
        break;
    }
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 87:
        key_pressed_w = false;
        break;

      case 83:
        key_pressed_s =false;
        break;

      case 65:
        key_pressed_a = false;
        break;

      case 68:
        key_pressed_d =false;
        break;
    }
  }, false);

  window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
      };
  })();

  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/16546061/6716639
  function render_image(img, x, y, width, height, degrees) {

    //Convert degrees to radian
    var rad = degrees * Math.PI / 180;

    //Set the origin to the center of the image
    ctx.translate(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);

    //Rotate the canvas around the origin
    ctx.rotate(rad);

    //draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(img,width / 2 * (-1),height / 2 * (-1),width,height);

    //reset the canvas
    ctx.rotate(rad * ( -1 ) );
    ctx.translate((x + width / 2) * (-1), (y + height / 2) * (-1));
  }

  function updateGame() {

    if(key_pressed_w) {
      player_x += player_speed * Math.sin(player_angle);
      player_y += player_speed * Math.cos(player_angle);
    }
    else if(key_pressed_s) {
      player_y += player_speed;
    }
    else if(key_pressed_a) {
      player_angle -= max_turn_angle;
    }
    else if(key_pressed_d) {
      player_angle += max_turn_angle;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    render_image(car_image, player_x, player_y, car_image.width, car_image.height, player_angle);

    requestAnimFrame(function() {
      updateGame();
    });
  }

  updateGame();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed the functions up, x should use cosine and y should use sine.

It's also worthy to mention, that these use radians instead of degrees, and by the look of things, your code uses degrees.

And also, the trigonometric functions with an angle of 0 create a vector pointing to the right, so if your car's image isn't correct, then it will go sideways.

Comment: Thanks, switching those functions and changing the degrees to radians fixed it.  Would I be best off just rotating the .png file or do you know of a simple way to make angle 0 point upwards?

Comment: @Kertigen just rotate the image